# replace all deprecated and removed functions in PHP

Tags: php

I once found a PHP file I could include, that fixes all problems automatically with functions that don't exist any more in a new PHP version by serving replacement functions automatically. Just include the file at the beginning of your old application and it works again in newer PHP versions. But I am not lucky with finding this any more.

It can use `function_exists()`, for example

```
if(!function_exists('ereg')){
    function ereg($pattern, $string, &$array) 
    { 
        return preg_match('#'.$pattern.'#', $string, $array); 
    }
}
```

and `version_compare`:

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.0.0', '<')) {
  ...
```

Is there a way to easily include a php fix that manages all problems between different PHP versions?

For example, I created an include, that replaces all mysql functions with the corresponding mysqli functions: [fix_mysql.inc.php](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/1db052edd8d723b59c79790b42635f1e)

(I am now mainly searching for a replacement for the old sqlite-functions by the Sqlite3 class)

Comment: terrible idea, fix them manually/

Comment: sure, fixing it would be a desireable solution, but why terrible? if it is a large php suite, that could take months, instead of fixing it with just one include file

Comment: There were reasons to break backward compatibility by removing these functions. Restoring them (if that's possible at all) would counteract those reasons and possibly introduce lots of issues again. You could run an old PHP version, btw, unless you care for security fixes and updates, but then you probably shouldn't run that code you're working on either.

Comment: there was a component to achieve PHP version independence in 2008 at https://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat/ maybe this is a continuation of that project: https://github.com/pear/PHP_Compat

Answer (score -2):

`error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE);`

This may help you for suppressing else you need to do that manually.

Comment: not really, I am looking for an include file that I could include in my old application, that fixes all the errors due to the PHP version change automatically

Comment: @rubo77 you can use `error_reporting(E_ALL &amp; ~E_DEPRECATED &amp; ~E_NOTICE);` for suppressing error which are due to deprecated functions.

Comment: Also, I think there is no other way for this. I have edited the original answer.

Comment: suppressing the errors dont bring back functions, that have been removed. Only deprecated errors are suppressed this way

Comment: Okay, if this is the case then you should use try catch block (Within whole file or in some smarter way ) and catch exceptions (and deprecated functions) and further manually modify them in future.

Comment: @ManishSharma: I appreciate your ideas, but did you read my question? I am looking for an include file, that fixes everything without me having to modify my code

Comment: @rubo77 I believe there is no any automated way to do this. If you found any let me know, I will update it to my knowledge database. ;) Thanks.

Comment: I will continue my search. meanwhile, you can have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer maybe you can improve your answer so far that it explains a bit more of the problem